# clang-format seems to ignore CommentPragmas

Tags: clang-format

I have the following CommentPragmas setting:

```
CommentPragmas: 'MARKER'
```

And I expect this to make clang-format (version 8.0.0) ignore the comments in this piece of code:

```
    enum bar {
    // MARKER: foo
        hello = 1
    // MARKER: foo
    };
```

However, clang-format indents these comments (aligning them with `hello = 1`). Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Yes, this is what I call truly horrible here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76183575/force-clang-format-not-to-touch-comments-at-all

Answer (score 3):

You're not doing anything wrong, this is just what clang-format does. `CommentPragmas` prevents breaking comments into multiple lines, but does not prevent indenting them.

I had thought this was documented, but now I see that it isn't. :(

Comment: @"Eric Backus" any idea how to prevent identing specific comments with a recent version of clang-format?

Comment: @Sonic78 Not that I'm aware of, but I haven't been paying enough attention to know if a recent version added this capability.