# Force clang-format not to touch comments at all

Tags: c++, format, clang-format

I intentionally provide some comments at the beginning of the lines, for example some debug code and do not want to indent these lines. I am OK clang-format not to touch // comments at all. All of them. Only setting I have found is `ReflowComments=false` which still idents the comments.

I have not found any setting to not indent comments and if I do the following

```
    {
// clang-format off
//comment
// clang-format on
    }
```

It is reformatted

```
    {
    // clang-format off
//comment
    // clang-format on
    }
```

Which is trully horrible. Of course I wish that `clang-format` won't tocuch `//clang-format off` and `//clang-format on` lines as well.

Comment: "Horrible" compared to what alternative?

Comment: `//clang-format off` is then indented and put out of the flow with the rest of the comment

Comment: Is it important that those are not indented as well?

Comment: Sure, I don't like it that way. Especially when the unformatted comment is one block and the clang-format off is there just to disable formatting of that block, it is then natural that it shall be indented with that block as well. Is there a way how to disable indenting comments at all. I want to format my source code, not my comments.

Comment: `clang-format` is open source, and you can submit a pull request adding the formatting functionality you want in it.

Comment: Also, you may be able to cheese it by starting column-zero comments with `#// tricky trick`.